# Simple active federation from third-party id providers

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, saml, ws-federation

I have a secure web application that I wish to expose to partners so their clients can capture information directly into a form hosted on my application.

The form will be shown in an iframe embedded within the partners web application. The URL of the iframe will point to my application and contain some form of session token that I issued to the partner before they rendered the iframe.

I don't want to store the user's credentials in my app I just need a mechanism to validate with the partner that the user is authenticated by them and authorised to perform the action I am hosting.

I have looked at SAML and oAuth but both seem incredibly complex for the identity provider to implement. I'd rather implement most of the complexity myself and provide the partner with an easy means of integrating.

i.e. The key is finding a solution that is simple for the identity provider

**Example:**

Partner requests a session token from me via some predefined endpoint (they would specify the action that their user will need to perform, the user's username or id and client token to validate the response).

https://myapp.com/getsession/?username=bob&action=action1&token=CLIENT_SESSION_TOKEN

I return a SERVICE_SESSION_TOKEN.

Partner embeds iframe with the following URL in their app:

https://myapp.com/action1/?username=bob&token=SERVICE_SESSION_TOKEN

I validate the token and create an authenticated session for the user with authority to perform action1.

I return the form for action1 and it is rendered in the iframe.

When the user submits the form I can notify the partner of this by redirecting the iframe to

https://partner.com/action1_callback/?username=bob&token=CLIENT_SESSION_TOKEN&result=RESULT

Is there a standard that supports such a protocol? oAuth and SAML make the identity provision very complex.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Simple Web Token (SWT)? The token has a simple format like for example:

```
Issuer=partner.com&ExpiresOn=1262304000&Username=Bob&ClientSessionToken=B2202256-76A6-4527-8439-E6C3F017F414&HMACSHA256=AT55%2B2jLQeuigpg0xm%2Fvn7tjpSGXBUfFe0UXb0%2F9opE%3D
```

There is only one required parameter `HMACSHA256` which secures the token from tampering.
`Issuer` and `ExpiresOn` parameters recommended to use to identify the issuer of the token and restrict the time of token validity. Other parameters depend on the information you need to pass in the token.